# Make Redis unixsocket owned by redis user

Tags: unix, redis, debian

I have installed Redis 3.0.6 on Debian. There's a `/etc/init.d/redis` file which starts the Redis server when the system starts or I can invoke it manually to start/stop the server. Problem is that this script is run as root user.

I have a `redis` user and group that I want to make Redis run under. But I can't figure out how (I have not found an option to make Redis switch user ID after startup). In my config file I use

```
unixsocket /home/redis/redis.sock
unixsocketperm 770
```

But, of course, the `redis.sock` is owned by `root`.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 redis redis  4096 Jan 18 03:34 bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 redis redis  4096 Jan 18 03:55 data
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis redis 41638 Jan 18 03:52 redis.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis redis 16348 Jan 18 03:55 redis.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root      5 Jan 18 03:55 redis.pid
srwxrwx--- 1 root  root      0 Jan 18 03:55 redis.sock
```

And the process is, too.

```
root      7913  0.1  0.1  38016  1976 ?        Ssl  03:55   0:00 /home/redis/bin/redis-server *:6379
```

Ultimately, I have a `git` user that is also in the `redis` group and thus should in the end have access to `redis.sock`. (This is for a manual deployment of GitLab CE).

How I can I configure the Redis server that way?

Comment: what if you create socket in `/tmp`? As I tried with redis 3. socket owner remains to redis user itself

Comment: @AliNikneshan I can try, but the redis user is also `root`, which I would like to change as well. I just don't know how

Comment: normally init.d scripts impersonate themselves to user during the run. run `ps -ef|grep redis-server` and check if daemon runs on redis user.

Comment: @AliNikneshan I started redis using `sudo service redis start`. It is now running under the `root` user. `root      7913     1  0 03:55 ?        00:00:06 /home/redis/bin/redis-server *:6379` This is the `/etc/init.d/redis` script: http://pastebin.com/a5BUSscw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your /etc/init.d to use `sudo` during start service (line 33):

```
sudo -u redis $EXEC $CONF
```

You may need to cleanup old files (in `/var/lib`) or reset their permission to redis.